# Angular CLI - Dev Experience - 500 Requests

Tags: systemjs, angular-cli

I'm using the Angular Cli project structure out of the box https://github.com/angular/angular-cli

A default Single Page app is 500 requests , 9MB , 10 seconds on my local box. I realize that this is the dev build but there is no way my app needs all these scripts. And its quiet annoying for me to wait so long after dev changes to reload the page.

What i would like to do is figure out how i can know what i can remove and add so i can tailor it down to whats really by used (aside from changing away from system js to another bundler). Any guidelines on streamlining this?

Comment: FYI, there are fixes to address this for both local development and release in progress.

Comment: OK, cool know any details on that? I could watch...

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/909 and https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/1325

Comment: Super helpful thanks